# Displaying an image in a text widget in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, path, widget

I would like to display a image (stored on my own website) in a text widget.

I typed the following code in a text widget in the wp-admin interface:

```
<b>See on the map</b> <br> <i>Get Directions</i>
<IMG SRC="<?php 
  bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/buon-appetitoDrottingatan.jpg"         
   ALT="Buon Appetito!" WIDTH=170 HEIGHT=130px>

    <br>Drottingatan, 67 Stockholm, Tel: 08-11-22-33
```

But the picture is not displayed. What is the path to the text widget?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant use php inside the text widget you will have to hard code the img straight into it.

ie:

```
<b>See on the map</b> <br> <i>Get Directions</i>
<img src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/yourthemefolder/buon-appetitoDrottingatan.jpg" alt="Buon Appetito!" width="170" height="130px" />
<br>Drottingatan, 67 Stockholm, Tel: 08-11-22-33
```

either that or host the file on a image hosting site and link through from that..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the php code you posted in a sidebar or any future code snipets you can do such with the following wordpress plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

you can use your code. This is practical if you have a big chunk of code.